# Create new Attribute in Weka (String)

Tags: java, weka, arff

So my question is how do I declare a new attribute for weka when all my data is a collection of texts.

My goal is to create new attributes, so that I can use a decision tree algorithm.
For example, I want an attribute that Filters for all these Keywords (Winner, Free, Subscription)

[ARFF File viewed in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYYcX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of generating new attributes from the textual data in your `STRING` attribute, then you can use the [StringToWordVector](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) filter.

For general info on handling textual data, have a look at the [Text categorization with Weka](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/text_categorization_with_weka/) wiki article.